# How to block when someone accesses the Ip through the browser

Tags: networking, browser, ip, nginx, help-files

I am using Debian, Nginx

I am a little novice in nginx

I have purchased a VPS Server, when I access my IP 33.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx through my browser either as https:// IP or http:// IP my website content is displayed, as if I had entered my domain.com in the browser.

In this case I would like to display some blocking warning like 403 Forbidden or if you can show me how to redirect the visitor who accesses the IP to a blank page.

Thanks

Comment: You do realise that the connection to your website is by ipaddress:port ?  Simplisticly, the domain name is an index at the Domain Name Servers to obtain the ipaddress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `server_name www.example.com;` directive in your server block in the NGINX config, instead of `server_name _;` which matches everything.

You need two server blocks. One with a `server_name` matching your domain name, that serves the proper website. And another with `server_name _;` as a catch all that serves a error page.

See here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/